# How to record a call using twilio taskrouter conference instruction?

Tags: twilio, twilio-api

I am creating a call center app, in which I am using taskrouter conference instruction to connect agent and customer.  Below is my conference instruction in assignment callback.

```
assignment_instruction = {
                instruction: 'conference',
                from: attributes["from"],
                Record: true,
                RecordingStatusCallback: "/handle-record?taskId="+attributes["sf_taskId"],
                post_work_activity_sid: "WA30809afd42e2972a13b5e90f138ece41"
            }
```

I have tried various ways like record='record-from-start' or record='true' but its still not working.  Can someone let me know what I am missing.

Comment: Are you doing this in response to a webhook or using the TaskRouter JavaScript?

Comment: @philnash it is in response to webhook.

Comment: Hey, so I've discovered you're also talking with Twilio support about this, which is great! It might be best to come to a solution with them and then update this question with an answer once it's is sorted.

Comment: Could you please update with your solution? having the same issue

Answer (score 0):

```
"conference_record": "true"
```

Use the above parameter, in the assignment callback, it will start the recording as soon as conference starts.

Here are other options

```
conference_status_callback
conference_status_callback_method
conference_status_callback_event
conference_recording_status_callback
conference_recording_status_callback_method
conference_trim
conference_record
end_conference_on_exit
start_conference_on_enter
beep_on_customer_entrance (boolean)
end_conference_on_customer_exit (boolean)
```