# Twilio TaskRouter: Need Help in Conference Call

Tags: twilio, twilio-php, twilio-taskrouter, twilio-conference

I use task router enqueue and dequeue instructions to connect the caller to the worker. Everything is working perfectly fine. Now I want to add another agent in the same call. For that purpose, I need to convert that call into a conference.
I am using Laravel. Here is I am enqueuing the call

```
$taskAttributes = [
        'channel' => 'voice', // Specify that it's a voice call
        'type' => $deptName,
        'departmentId' => $department_id,
    ];
    $enqueue->task(json_encode($taskAttributes),['timeout' => 60]);
    return response($response)->header('Content-Type', 'text/xml');
```

That is how I am dequeuing it

```
return response()->json([
            "instruction" => "dequeue",
            "status_callback_events" => "initiated,ringing,answered,completed",
            "record" => "record-from-answer",
            "status_callback_url" => url('ivr/statuseventCallback'),
        ]);
```

What I need is to convert the in progress call to conference so I can add another person to the same call.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I managed to do that.  Sharing here for information.

When the Call is attended and in progress. I trigger an API to update the task

```
$task = $twilio->taskrouter->v1->workspaces($workspaceSid)
                            ->tasks($taskSid)->fetch()->toArray();

        $existing = json_decode($task['attributes'],true);
        $new = [
            "conference" => "redirect"
        ];
        $updated = array_merge($existing,$new);
        // dd($task['attributes']);
        $task = $twilio->taskrouter->v1->workspaces($workspaceSid)
                            ->tasks($taskSid)
                            ->update([
                                    "attributes" => json_encode($updated)
                                ]
                            );
```

Now every event in my webhook call will have this attribute in Task Detail.
I am updating first the child leg of the call then the parent leg.

```
if(isset($taskAttributes['conference'])){
   $task = isset($postDate['TaskSid']) ? $postDate['TaskSid'] : '';
   $twilio = new Client($accountSid, $authToken);
   $twilio->calls($callData['call_sid'])->update([
      "method" => "POST",
       "url" => url('api/phone/addConf?tsid='.$task),
   ]);
   $twilio->calls($taskAttributes['call_sid'])->update([
       "method" => "POST",
       "url" => url('api/phone/addConf?tsid='.$task),
   ]);
} catch (Exception $e) {
  setErrorLogs('Twilio callIsNotUpdating'.$e->getMessage());
}             
exit;}
```

on this addconf just return the twiml conference.

Answer (score 0):

Skip the "dequeue" and use the [Conference Instruction](https://www.twilio.com/docs/taskrouter/api/reservations?code-sample=code-update-conference-instructions&code-language=PHP&code-sdk-version=7.x#conference):

> Conference instruction is the recommended way to connect calls between
> customer and agents. This should be used in almost all cases instead
> of dequeue or call for call center scenarios

The documentation for the [POST Parameters](https://www.twilio.com/docs/taskrouter/api/reservations?code-sample=code-update-conference-instructions&code-language=PHP&code-sdk-version=7.x#post-parameters-3):

> Conference instruction uses the [Conference Participants API](https://www.twilio.com/docs/voice/api/conference-participant-resource) . **All
> values valid for that API can be provided as part of the conference
> instruction.** Note that those parameter names are not replicated here.
> Please refer to linked documentation for valid values.

I added the bolded part about "all values valid" because this isn't super clear in the documentation.

Your code would look something like this:

```
return response()->json([
            "instruction" => "conference",
            "conference_status_callback_event" => "start,end,join,leave,mute,hold",
            "conference_record" => "record-from-start",
            "conference_status_callback_url" => url('ivr/statuseventCallback'),
        ]);
```

This stackoverflow [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/76255559/how-to-configure-conference-from-a-twilio-taskrouter-conference-instruction) has some additional tips.

Comment: Thank you for the explanation but I have already configured the conference perfectly and it is working fine. But the problem here is simultaneous ringing is not supported with instruction conferences.  I need to ring all workers at the same time.
Apparently this scenario worked with dequeue but not conference.

Comment: @YasirIjaz, you can convert a Voicecall to a Conference using the Redirect verb and supplying the Conference Twiml. However, what you actually need to do is convert two different calls (agent and customer) to a Conference. This is going to be problematic due to timing and my guess is you will get a lot disconnects. All this would be easy if you just start with a Conference - they are only marginally more expensive than a Voicecall. A Conference with just two people is typical to unlock all the features of the Conference.